# Loading file from HDFS in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

I'm trying to run this spark program from HDFS because when I run it locally I don't have enough memory on my pc to handle it. Can someone inform me on how to load the csv file from my HDFS as opposed to doing it locally? Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

public class VideoGamesSale {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("Video Games Spark")
            .config("spark.master", "local")
            .getOrCreate();
```

Comment: `spark.read().csv("hdfs://namenode:port/path/to/file.csv")` should create a data frame from the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to create a dataset/dataframe from a csv file.

```
Dataset<Row> csvDS = spark.read().csv("/path/of/csv/file.csv");
```

If you want to read multiple files from directories you can use the below

```
Seq<String> paths = scala.collection.JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(Arrays.asList("path1","path2"));
Dataset<Row> csvsDS = spark.read().csv(paths);
```